# Laravel Collection ordered by day of the week M-F

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-collection

I have a Laravel collection grouped by day of the week but they are in the wrong order. I need them ordered by day of the week starting with Monday.

My Controller:

```
public function getWeeklySchedule()
    {
        $testSchedule = VolunteerSchedule::all();

        $result = $testSchedule->groupBy(['assignment', function ($item) {
            return $item['scheduled_days'];
        }]);

        return $result;
    }
```

The result looks like this:

```
  "Wednesday": {
    "kitchen": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "full_name": "Hipolito Carroll",
        "created_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z"
      }
    ],
    "driver": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "full_name": "Prof. Conor Grimes I",
        "created_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z"
      }
    ],
    "bagger": [
      {
        "id": 4,
        "full_name": "Martine Kemmer Sr.",
        "created_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z"
      },
      {
        "id": 10,
        "full_name": "Marcellus Walker",
        "created_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Thursday": {
    "kitchen": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "full_name": "Hipolito Carroll",
        "created_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "full_name": "Leonardo Schaefer V",
        "created_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z"
      }
    ],
    "driver": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "full_name": "Prof. Conor Grimes I",
        "created_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "full_name": "Prof. Pablo Corwin",
        "created_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z"
      }
    ],
    "bagger": [
      {
        "id": 6,
        "full_name": "Samantha Feil",
        "created_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z"
      },
      {
        "id": 10,
        "full_name": "Marcellus Walker",
        "created_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Friday": {
    "kitchen": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "full_name": "Hipolito Carroll",
        "created_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z"
      }
    ],
    "driver": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "full_name": "Prof. Conor Grimes I",
        "created_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z"
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "full_name": "Miss Eleonore Kutch IV",
        "created_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z"
      }
    ],
    "bagger": [
      {
        "id": 4,
        "full_name": "Martine Kemmer Sr.",
        "created_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z"
      },
      {
        "id": 10,
        "full_name": "Marcellus Walker",
        "created_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Tuesday": {
    "kitchen": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "full_name": "Miss Lessie Torphy",
        "created_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "full_name": "Leonardo Schaefer V",
        "created_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z"
      }
    ],
    "bagger": [
      {
        "id": 10,
        "full_name": "Marcellus Walker",
        "created_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-11-05T17:33:52.000000Z"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Saturday": {...
```

Some fields have been removed for brevity. The days of the week are stored as a serialized array in the database. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define a [custom sort function](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sortby) that uses a map for the days of the week:

```php
$days = ["Monday" => 1, "Tuesday" => 2, "Wednesday" => 3, "Thursday" => 4, "Friday" => 5, "Saturday" => 6, "Sunday" => 7];
$collection = collect(["Friday" => [], "Wednesday" => [], "Tuesday" => []]);

$collection->sortBy(fn($val, $key) => $days[$key]);

dump($collection);
```

Output:

```
=> Illuminate\Support\Collection {#4977
     all: [
       "Tuesday" => [],
       "Wednesday" => [],
       "Friday" => [],
     ],
   }
```

So your code becomes:

```php
public function getWeeklySchedule(): Collection
{
    $days = ["Monday" => 1, "Tuesday" => 2, "Wednesday" => 3, "Thursday" => 4, "Friday" => 5, "Saturday" => 6, "Sunday" => 7];

    return VolunteerSchedule::all()
        ->groupBy(['assignment', fn ($item) => $item['scheduled_days']])
        ->sortBy(fn ($val, $key) => $days[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**It will 100% work. It will sort collection from monday to sunday.**

```
$ProductAvailabilities =ProductProductAvailability:get();
                    $days = [
                        'monday'=>1,
                        'tuesday'=>2,
                        'wednesday'=>3,
                        'thursday'=>4,
                        'friday'=>5,
                        'saturday'=>6,
                        'sunday'=>7
                    ];
    
                    $sortingDays = array();
                    foreach($days as $day => $value)
                    {
                        $sortingDays[] = $ProductAvailabilities->where('day_availability',$day);
                    }
   $ProductAvailabilities=collect($sortingDays)->flatten();
```